# Keep quality of jpg after converting from pdf to jpg with pdflibnet and c#

Tags: c#, pdf, jpeg

I using this code for converting a pdf file to jpg images, but the quality of jpg's images is very poor; someone knows how change the quality or keep the quality of pdf?
I'm working on a multipage pdf with excelent quality.
Sorry for my bad English.

```
 public void ConvertPDFtoJpg(string filename, string dirOut)
    {
        string[] archivo = filename.Split('\\');
        string final = archivo[3].Replace(".pdf", "");
        string archOri = final;

        PDFLibNet.PDFWrapper _pdfDoc = new PDFLibNet.PDFWrapper();
        _pdfDoc.LoadPDF(filename);

        int p = 1;

        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.10.25;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=BECO");
        con1.Open();

        for (int s = 0; s < _pdfDoc.PageCount; s++)
        {
            Image img = RenderPage(_pdfDoc, s);
            string rutaFin = final + ".page" + p + ".jpg";
            img.Save(Path.Combine(dirOut, string.Format(rutaFin)));

            string textoCmd = "INSERT into imagenes (ruta1,valor,estado) VALUES ('" + rutaFin +"', '"+ archOri +"', 0)";
            SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand(textoCmd, con1);
            com4.ExecuteNonQuery();

            p++;
        }
        _pdfDoc.Dispose();
        con1.Close();

    }
    public Image RenderPage(PDFLibNet.PDFWrapper doc, int page)
    {
        doc.CurrentPage = page + 1;
        doc.CurrentX = 0;
        doc.CurrentY = 0;

        doc.RenderPage(IntPtr.Zero);

        // create an image to draw the page into
        var buffer = new Bitmap(doc.PageWidth, doc.PageHeight);
        doc.ClientBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, doc.PageWidth, doc.PageHeight);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(buffer))
        {
            var hdc = g.GetHdc();
            try
            {
                doc.DrawPageHDC(hdc);
            }
            finally
            {
                g.ReleaseHdc();
            }
        }
        return buffer;

    }
```

Comment: When you quality, are you referring to the recreation of the image or the resolution of the image?

Comment: i'm refering to the recreation of the imagen after convertion, because when zooming in the created image is distorted.

Comment: Can you post a sample before and after image? I'm guessing that the original images are bitonal and the process is creating an 8-bit JPEG out of it when a more appropriate option would be 1-bpp flate or G4 coded.

Comment: It looks like then you are printing your image into a bitmap the size of the PDF, rather than the size of the image. Therefore, when you zoom you get low resolution.

Comment: i can't post an image because i'm new user; the pdf file is in excelent quality but after conversion to jpg the quality is very poor, anyone know of any code to give quality to the image created, i need a sample code for this please

Comment: I'd suggest using a command line utility that extracts the image from the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Matias,

What you'll need to do is add a line to specify your output DPI in the RenderPage method.

Ex:

```
...
doc.CurrentX = 0;
doc.CurrentY = 0;

doc.RenderDPI = 300;
...
```

In this case I set it to 300 DPI which gives you much more detail.